# Login user Information on home page

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, user-profile, user-profile-property

I am using SharePoint online. I want to show basic details(with picture) of currently login user at Home page.  Means every user will see his/her own details in their homepage.

Any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Script Editor Web Part to the home Page and then use JavaScript/jQuery/REST API to get required information. Use HTML/CSS to present it in nice and friendly way.

http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/02/sharepoint-2013-working-with-user.html

```
(function($){

  $(document).ready(function(){         
    // Ensure that the SP.UserProfiles.js file is loaded before the custom code runs.
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadUserData, 'SP.UserProfiles.js'); 
  });

  var userProfileProperties;

  function loadUserData(){

    //Get Current Context   
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    //Get Instance of People Manager Class
    var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

    //Get properties of the current user
    userProfileProperties = peopleManager.getMyProperties();

    clientContext.load(userProfileProperties);

    //Execute the Query.
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);

  }

  function onSuccess() {        

    alert(userProfileProperties.get_displayName());

  }

  function onFail(sender, args) {
    alert("Error: " + args.get_message());
  } 

})(jQuery);
```